# Jetpack Compose. Круг. Адаптивная верстка

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Мне необходимо, чтобы размер круга был задан не точными параметрами, а процентными. Но при разных разрешениях экрана, круг едет. Может быть есть функция в Kotlin, которая возвращает ширину и высоту экрана?

```
Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Black, CircleShape)
            .fillMaxHeight(0.25f)
            .fillMaxWidth(0.5f)
    ) {
    }
```

Comment: Ну узнать размеры области можно с помощью `BoxWithConstraints`, но зачем это знание? `Modifier.aspectRatio` даст вам правильную высоту

Comment: Да, спасибо. Modifier.aspectRatio помогло

Answer (score 0):

Тут несколько вариантов, либо писать свой Layout со своей логикой размещения.
Либо же использовать BoxWithConstraints который в своем скоупе возвращает доступную высоту и ширину. Для того чтобы он возвращал всю высоту и ширину экрана необходимо применить к нему модификатор fillMaxSize()